# Total differentiation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For each of the functions below use the total diferential to
approximate the change in $Y$ due to the given changes in $X$ and $Z$:

$Y= X^2 + 4X -Z^2 -2XZ$, where $X=1$ and $Z = 4$ , and $\Delta X=2$ and $\Delta Z = -2$

I have a bunch of these questions to do and this seems to be the easiest of them. I understand how to partially differentiate and find $YX$ and $YZ$ but I'm having trouble with figuring out how to use those numbers for $X$ and $Y$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By "triangle X", do you mean $\Delta X$?

Comment: sorry that's the one i meant just couldn't figure out how to type it

Comment: Looks like someone got it.

Comment: @ml0105 For $X_1-X_2$, use $\Delta X$ (`\Delta X`), not $\triangle X$ (`\triangle X`).

Comment: Would you know how to proceed if $Y$ depended only on one variable, say $X$?

Comment: I'm not to sure exactly all i know is from what we've been doing its something to do with partially differentiating just X and then just Z and changing the values but apart from that i'm really lost with this question